# Django Multipart/form-data serialization attrs are empty

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data, form-data

I have an issue when trying to serialize `multipart/form-data`.

```
class View(GenericAPIView):

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = QS.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, )


class SampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    event = serializers.CharField()
    kwargs = serializers.DictField(required=False)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        print(attrs) // result:  { event: "request", kwargs: {} }
```

Why do I get empty `kwargs` in the serializer validate method? Do I need a different parser?

I tried using different parsers but they do not seem to work. The initial data is:

[image]

```
-----------------------------23641203962992511458665574039
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="event"

request
-----------------------------23641203962992511458665574039
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="kwargs[email]"

sample email
-----------------------------23641203962992511458665574039--
```